# how to split the value and assign a boolean value and convert into dict pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split the value by delimiter | and for each value it has to be assigned True.

```
ID   Condition
1    Null
2    NP
3    NP|KH
4    KH|PR|MM

output
ID   Condition
1    null
2    {"NP"=True}
3    {"NP"=True,"KH"=True}
4    {"KH"=True,"PR"=True,"MM"=True}
```

I am trying with this code but i am mising something

```
for v in df.Condition:
            if not pd.isna(v):
                if not "|" in v:
                    v={v:True}
                else:
                    key= v.split("|")
                    d=[]
                    for i in range(0,len(key)):
                        d.append({key[i]:True})
```

But this is saving the result as [{"NP"=True},{"KH"=True}]

Can anyone please help me get the output in right format?

Comment: Did you incidentally type "=" instead of ":"? `[{"NP"=True},{"KH"=True}]` is not legal in Python. Also, what is `Null`? Is it `np.nan`?

Comment: `if not "|" in v:` split is redundant. `v.split` returns `[v]` if there is no separator in `v`.

Comment: null is np.Nan.. Actually d.append({key[i]:True}) saves the reuslt as [{"NP"=True},{"KH"=True}]. but i am looking for {"NP"=True,"KH"=True}

Comment: Once again, `{"NP"=True}` is not valid in Python. I dunno where you got it. `{"NP": True}` is corect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumptions in the comment are correct:

```
mask = df.Condition.notnull()
result = df.loc[mask, 'Condition']\
           .str.split("|")\
           .apply(lambda cond: {term: True for term in cond})
#1                            {'NP': True}
#2                {'NP': True, 'KH': True}
#3    {'KH': True, 'PR': True, 'MM': True}
```

You can put the results back into the original dataframe:

```
df.loc[mask, 'Condition'] = result
```

Comment: this worked. so i have dataframe and then i have to convert that specific column in Dict format and i have to parse my entire dataframe into a json file.. for condition column for any value it has be true in dict format {"NP"=True} while send the file

Answer (score 0):

Why have you defined d as a list? That's what the wrong with this your code. Define d as a dictionary as following and run your code. You will get the answer in right format.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("t.csv")
for v in df.Condition:
    if not pd.isna(v):
        if not "|" in v:
            v={v:True}
            print(v)
        else:
            key= v.split("|")
            d={}
            for i in range(0,len(key)):
                d[key[i]]=True
            print(d)
```

And the second place where you have done wrong is in the data frame. Pandas will take Null as "Null" (a string) . and it will give a wrong result. So keep the place a blank inside the file you reading or of you are creating a df manually, keep that place as numpy.NaN

Comment: thank you .. i am new to pandas and i am a learner and tried something on my own.. thank you for your tip..

Answer (score 0):

I think Something like this will work for you:

```
import numpy
import pandas


# Create some dummy data
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Condition':[numpy.nan, 'NP', 'NP|KH', 'KH|PR|MM',]})

df.assign(Condition=df.apply(lambda row: {
    item: True
    for items in row.str.split('|')
    if type(items) == list
    for item in items
}, axis=1))
```

Note that this results in a empty dict instead of a null for null items.

```
                              Condition
0                                    {}
1                          {'NP': True}
2              {'NP': True, 'KH': True}
3  {'KH': True, 'PR': True, 'MM': True}
```

if it is important to have `NaN`s instead of empty dicts you could follow this with

```
df.assign(Condition=df.apply(lambda row: row if row.iloc[0] else numpy.nan, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

use split and a findall regular expression

```
txt="""1    Null
2    NP
3    NP|KH
4    KH|PR|MM"""

elements=txt.split("\n")
for element in elements:
    matches=re.findall(r'([0-9]+\s+)([A-Za-z|]+)', element)
    output=""
    for match in matches:
        elements=match[1].split("|")
        #for element in elements:
        if len(elements)>1:
            output="=True,".join(elements)
        elif elements[0]!="Null":
            output=str(elements[0])+"=True"
        else:
            output=str(elements[0])
        print(output)
```

output:

```
Null
NP=True
NP=True,KH
KH=True,PR=True,MM
​
```